# Bevy 0.10: How do I render 3D text in bevy? (using font.ttf file)

Tags: rust, game-development, bevy

I am developing a card game for which I need to render some **3d** text. The game itself is designed to be 3d, however the card graphics are `.png` files (so effectively 2d) which I am rendering using the [`shape::Quad`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.10.1/bevy/prelude/shape/struct.Quad.html) + [`StandardMaterial.base_color_texture`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.10.1/bevy/pbr/struct.StandardMaterial.html#structfield.base_color_texture) to `asset_server.load("cards/example.png")` on a [`PbrBundle`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.10.1/bevy/pbr/type.PbrBundle.html).
I don't know any other way of rendering effectively 2d content (e.g. icons) in a 3d context, this technique was even used in the official bevy examples to render text [here](https://bevyengine.org/examples/3d/texture/).

My problem comes when I want to render text, e.g. numbers, as part of the game. Ideally, I would like to spawn an entity with a `Transform` and a custom component which I can `Query<&mut CardNumberComponent>` to update, which is rendered by my `Camera3dBundle` as a 'normal mesh' alongside other entities (mostly `PbrBundle`s), but is rendered as text. For example, I want to create a 'card' entities which aesthetically totals to a 2d image (normal `PbrBundle` + custom material as described above) *and* a health total, the health total being specifically a *number* that is part of the 3d 'card' entities (probably a child), so when I move the card the number moves with the card (like a child `PbrBundle` entity moves with its parent entity as shown in [this official bevy example](https://bevyengine.org/examples/3d/parenting/)).

My current attempts to achieve such "`Text3dBundle`" like behaviour have partially succeeded, if I know the range of possible numbers (or more generally text) that I need I can pre-generate images and call `asset_server.load(format!("cards/nums/number_{}.png), x))`.
This works, but I wonder if I have simply missed some simple API provided by bevy or a third party crate.

#### Stated formally:

My problem requires this function, using bevy 0.10.1 (from `crates.io`) and compatible with macOS + WASM (`trunk serve` should 'just work'), spawns text into the bevy world:

```rust
pub fn render_text(
    at: Transform,
    content: &str,
    font_file: &str,
    commands: &mut Commands,
    asset_server: ResMut<AssetServer>,
    materials: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    meshs: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
// other bevy system parameters
) {
    // load font
    let font = asset_server.load(font_file);

    // create text
    let text_something_idk = todo!();

    // spawn in
    commands.spawn(text_something_idk);
}
```

**That is my problem, how do I render 3d text in bevy?**

##### Almost solution, WASM not supported

One way of solving this is to render the text you want + font file into a `.png` file at runtime as required. Then, theoretically you could save the data as a file locally and then load the same file as an asset in bevy. One such (working) implementation is this: (`cargo add text-to-png@0.1.1`)

```rust
fn text_to_image_runtime(text: &str, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) -> Handle<Image> {
    use text_to_png::TextRenderer;

    let renderer = TextRenderer::try_new_with_ttf_font_data(include_bytes!("font.ttf"))
        .expect("Could not load file");

    let text_png = renderer
        .render_text_to_png_data(text, 42, "white")
        .expect("Couldn't custom render text");

    // NOTE: This line will break on WASM
    std::fs::write(format!("assets/text-file-{}.png", text), text_png.data).expect("File works + not on WASM");

    asset_server.load(format!("text-file-{}.png", text))
}

pub fn render_text(...) {
// using PbrMesh with StandardMaterial.base_color_texture = text_to_image_runtime(text)
}
```

The issue is, I need my game to support `WASM` targets and `std::fs` is basically unavailable in the browser, so I have no way of passing the `png` data to the bevy `asset_server` without using `asset_server.load` so that I can render the custom `png` as a texture as a text representation in my game.
If only there was an `let img: Handle<image> = asset_server.load_from_bytes(input_bytes)` API, this solution could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly mentioned

> but I wonder if I have simply missed some simple API provided by bevy or a third party crate.

I will provide a sample on how this could be done using my crate [`meshtext`](https://crates.io/crates/meshtext):

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;
use meshtext::{MeshGenerator, MeshText, TextSection};

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .insert_resource(Msaa::Sample4)
        .insert_resource(ClearColor(Color::Rgba {
            red: 1f32,
            green: 1f32,
            blue: 1f32,
            alpha: 1f32,
        }))
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .add_system(rotate_system)
        .run();
}

#[derive(Component)]
struct RotationEntity;

/// set up a simple 3D scene with text
fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {
    let font_data = include_bytes!("../assets/font/FiraMono-Regular.ttf");
    let mut generator = MeshGenerator::new(font_data);
    let transform = Mat4::from_scale(Vec3::new(1f32, 1f32, 0.2f32)).to_cols_array();
    let text_mesh: MeshText = generator
        .generate_section(&"Hello World!".to_string(), false, Some(&transform))
        .unwrap();

    let vertices = text_mesh.vertices;
    let positions: Vec<[f32; 3]> = vertices.chunks(3).map(|c| [c[0], c[1], c[2]]).collect();
    let uvs = vec![[0f32, 0f32]; positions.len()];

    let mut mesh = Mesh::new(bevy::render::render_resource::PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, positions);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs);
    mesh.compute_flat_normals();

    // text
    commands
        // use this bundle to change the rotation pivot to the center
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .with_children(|parent| {
            // parent is a ChildBuilder, which has a similar API to Commands
            parent.spawn(PbrBundle {
                mesh: meshes.add(mesh),
                material: materials.add(Color::rgb(1f32, 0f32, 0f32).into()),
                // transform mesh so that it is in the center
                transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(
                    text_mesh.bbox.size().x / -2f32,
                    0f32,
                    0f32,
                )),
                ..Default::default()
            });
        })
        .insert(RotationEntity);

    // light
    commands.spawn(PointLightBundle {
        point_light: PointLight {
            intensity: 1500.0,
            shadows_enabled: true,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
        ..Default::default()
    });
    // camera
    commands.spawn(Camera3dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 2.0, 6.0).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
        ..Default::default()
    });
}

fn rotate_system(time: Res<Time>, mut query: Query<(&mut Transform, With<RotationEntity>)>) {
    for (mut transform, _) in query.iter_mut() {
        transform.rotate_y(time.delta_seconds() as f32);
    }
}
```

Which will give you this:
[image: Bevy Graphics Output]

The full sample can be found [here](https://github.com/FrankenApps/bevy_meshtext_sample), including the [sample application running on wasm](https://frankenapps.github.io/bevy_meshtext_sample/).

Comment: Thanks that is an exact (although rather large) solution awesome!
Side note, how do you get relative `include_bytes!("../something")` to not give you an OS error saying 'no such file or directory' (on macOS specifically, I know that macro is platform specific)?

Comment: For me this works fine on macos are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Well, I feel dumb for saying this, but it works now. I must have had the path wrong because I would get an error like file not found at 'src/../assets/fonts/example.ttf' for an `include_bytes!("../assets/fonts/example.ttf")` (in src/lib.rs)
Anyway thanks so much for showing me the `mesh text` crate, I am building out a `Text3dBundle` and `Text3d` component implementation

Answer (score 0):

Using the `mesh text` crate, this work:

```rust
fn spawn_text(
    text: &str,
    center_pos: Transform,
    colour: Color,
    pixel_size: f32,

    commands: &mut Commands,
    (meshs, materials, _): &mut ASS,
) {
    let (mesh, offset) = get_text_mesh(text, pixel_size);

    // text
    commands
        // parent is a ChildBuilder, which has a similar API to Commands
        .spawn(PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshs.add(mesh),
            material: materials.add(colour.into()),
            // transform mesh so that it is in the center
            transform: center_pos.translate(offset),
            ..Default::default()
        });
}

/// Returns mesh + offset (to ensure coordinates start in center of text)
fn get_text_mesh(text: &str, pixel_size: f32) -> (Mesh, Vec3) {
    use meshtext::{MeshGenerator, MeshText, TextSection};
    let font_data = include_bytes!(concat!(
        env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"),
        "/assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.ttf"
    ));
    let mut generator = MeshGenerator::new(font_data);
    let transform = Mat4::from_scale(Vec3::new(pixel_size, pixel_size, 0.)).to_cols_array();
    let text_mesh: MeshText = generator
        .generate_section(text, true, Some(&transform))
        .unwrap();

    let vertices = text_mesh.vertices;
    let positions: Vec<[f32; 3]> = vertices.chunks(3).map(|c| [c[0], c[1], c[2]]).collect();
    let uvs = vec![[0f32, 0f32]; positions.len()];

    let mut mesh = Mesh::new(bevy::render::render_resource::PrimitiveTopology::TriangleList);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, positions);
    mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_UV_0, uvs);
    mesh.compute_flat_normals();

    (mesh, Vec3::X * (text_mesh.bbox.size().x / -2.) + Vec3::Y * (text_mesh.bbox.size().y / -2.))
}
```